# Go lang SHA3-256 gives invalid output?

Tags: go, cryptography

I am facing strange results fo `go` SHA3-256 function:
here is [source code](https://gist.github.com/r8d8/d206fb277d6bf34366d1854568517f8f)

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    pub, _ := hex.DecodeString("c342dbf7cdd3096c4c3910c511a57049e62847dd5030c7e644bc855acc1fd626")
    h := sha3.Sum256(pub[:])
    fmt.Printf("SHA3 %x\n", h)
    // expected: b32562e67d3ea44ba1367ce134caac49fd305b24cde6716ad3857ac682576379
    // received: 8a3ccc097f854811f4c49346da9c3bd1745d087ed539fa7817960f3e0ed8a44f
}
```

I verified result on couple of online converters, they all give same result, different from mine.

Comment: Do you have a question? Also, please make your questions self contained.

Comment: Print the result of `sha3.Sum256([]byte("c342dbf7cdd3096c4c3910c511a57049e62847dd‌​5030c7e644bc855acc1f‌​d626"))` and see the same "incorrect" result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that the online converters that you've tested perform hexadecimal decoding. They don't; they just take the ASCII/UTF-8/whatever value of the string and use that, i.e. they hash the text.

This can be easily observed by inputting your `c342...` string and then inputting `hello`. Both will work, while `hello` obviously doesn't contain hexadecimals. Another way is to start with an uppercase `C` instead of `c`, which will also return a different result, while the hexadecimal decoding should return an identical byte array and thus hash.

And a small Java application does indeed confirm your value of:

```
8a3ccc097f854811f4c49346da9c3bd1745d087ed539fa7817960f3e0ed8a44f
```

Note that most if not all online tools are basically hobby projects by amateur cryptographers. Expect all kind of encoding / decoding issues, errors and uncertainties in the implementation. If you want to test your implementation, use the official NIST test vectors.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten Bodewes, totaly missed that stuff with string.